# Command line tool or library to interrogate iSCSI target

Tags: linux-device-driver, scsi, iscsi

I'm trying to debug a problem with iPXE when it attempts to mount an iSCSI LUN from an LIO target. It's not getting the protocol quite right and that's leaving the LUN in a bad state.

I need the flexibility to manually replay the steps, and to compose some new ones, in order to figure out where it's going wrong.

It would be great if there were command line tools that can do this, but I'm betting I'll need to write it in C. Because SCSI makes heavy use of complex data structures I would find myself spending most of the time coding the structures unless I can find some iSCSI DDK which already has them.

Let me be clear if it wasn't already, I'm looking for more of an iSCSI DDK that will allow me to open the TCP socket and talk to the LIO Target. I AM NOT looking for tools or libraries to work with the client side Initiator API. It is in effect the initiator that's broken and I need tools to simulate one.

Also, this is quick and throw-away. I'm only looking for solutions that would accelerate what I need to do by hand.

_TIA

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found [libiscsi](https://github.com/sahlberg/libiscsi) which provides a framework and tests for Target Validation in addition. Worked great and got the problem solved.